# Proxy URL 'https://github.com%2Fkubernetes%2Fregistry.k8s.io' is not valid when I do start minishift with in my local windows machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, openshift, minishift

configured with below steps:

- downloaded the executable
- setted up the environment variable to run the minishift exe

I start Using the command:

```
minishift start --vm-driver virtualbox
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
Proxy URL 'https://github.com%2Fkubernetes%2Fregistry.k8s.io' is not valid.
```

I don't have any env with value:

```
Proxy URL 'https://github.com%2Fkubernetes%2Fregistry.k8s.io'
```

PS C:\Users\B.Jimmy> Get-ChildItem Env:

The list of environment variable:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\B.Jimmy\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME                   BBSRXLT043
ComSpec                        C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData                     C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOMEDRIVE                      C:
HOMEPATH                       \Users\B.Jimmy
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\B.Jimmy\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER                    \\BBSRXLT043
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           8
OneDrive                       C:\Users\B.Jimmy\OneDrive
OS                             Windows_NT
Path                           C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft S...
PATHEXT                        .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE         AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER           Intel64 Family 6 Model 126 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                6
PROCESSOR_REVISION             7e05
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432                   C:\Program Files
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\B.Jimmy\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShe...
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME                    Console
SystemDrive                    C:
SystemRoot                     C:\WINDOWS
TEMP                           C:\Users\B75E4~1.JIM\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP                            C:\Users\B75E4~1.JIM\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN                     BBSRXLT043
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE      BBSRXLT043
USERNAME                       B.Jimmy
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\B.Jimmy
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH          C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
windir                         C:\WINDOWS
```

If I do set up with HTTPS_PROXY env then also showing the same error
any suggestion would be helpful:)